# Total inventory in Postgresql using trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a RFID system that is recording tags going in and tags going out.
Recording each tag in a table (transactions). Header table (transaction_headers) has infromation about is the inventory coming in or going out. I will be using the first 8 char as a prefix to identify inventory. Then I want to count what is going in and out. Add to inventory what is coming in and subtract what is going out.

I have started with this SQL to get count of what is going in and out. How would i use this to get total inventory? And how to store this data.

```
SELECT Left(encoded_value,8) AS Itemnumber
      ,Count(transactions.encoded_value) AS CountOfencoded_value
      ,transaction_headers.loc_id AS Gate
      ,CASE WHEN transaction_headers.loc_id  = 1
            THEN Count(transactions.encoded_value) * -1
            ELSE  Count(transactions.encoded_value)
            END AS Inventory
FROM transactions 
INNER JOIN transaction_headers ON transactions.id = transaction_headers.id
GROUP BY Left(encoded_value,8), transaction_headers.loc_id
HAVING (((Left(encoded_value,8)) Like 'CCE1%') AND ((transaction_headers.loc_id) Is Not Null));
```

Transactions table

```
id  transaction_header_id   encoded_value
107039  6294    CCE1C0360000000017120ACA
107038  6294    CCE1C0360000000017120A8F
107037  6294    CCE1C0360000000017120418
107036  6294    CCE1C0360000000017120B5F
107035  6294    CCE1C0360000000018030802
107034  6294    CCE1E5000000000018090041
107033  6294    CCE1C0360000000018061053
106980  6295    CCE1C0360000000017120A8D
106979  6295    CCE1C0360000000018060670
106978  6295    CCE1C0360000000018060996
106977  6295    CCE1E5000000000018080331
```

header table

```
id  loc_id
6295    1
6294    2
```

Desired results are something like

Inventory in yard is:

```
ItemNumber     count
CCE1C036       3
CCE1E500       0
```

We will have thousands of transactions in a day and about 50 inventory codes

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What is your current results? What does not work?